# how to write with a single byte character encoding?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, ansi

I have a webservice that returns the config file to a low level hardware device.
The manufacturer of this device tells me he only supports single byte charactersets for this config file.

On [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS) I found out that the following should be single byte character sets:

- ISO 8859
- ISO/IEC 646 (I could not find this one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hf4sb8))
- various Microsoft/IBM code pages

But when I call Encoding.GetMaxByteCount(1) on these character sets it always returns 2.

I also tried various other encodings (for instance IBM437), but GetMaxByteCount also returns 2 for other character sets.

The method Endoding.IsSingleByte seems unreliable [according to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.issinglebyte)

> You should be careful in what your application does with the value for
>   IsSingleByte. An assumption of how an Encoding will proceed may still
>   be wrong. For example, Windows-1252 has a value of true for
>   Encoding.IsSingleByte, but Encoding.GetMaxByteCount(1) returns 2. This
>   is because the method considers potential leftover surrogates from a
>   previous decoder operation.

Also the method Encoding.GetMaxByteCount has some of the same issues [according to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getmaxbytecount#Y1128)

> Note that GetMaxByteCount considers potential leftover surrogates from
>   a previous decoder operation. Because of the decoder, passing a value
>   of 1 to the method retrieves 2 for a single-byte encoding, such as
>   ASCII. Your application should use the IsSingleByte property if this
>   information is necessary.

Because of this I am not sure anymore on what to use.

[Further reading](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: So just ignore MaxByteCount and use ASCII or any of those codepages.

Comment: So... avoid handing the encoding strings that you've received from a previous encoder that might have produced leftover surrogates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, `GetMaxByteCount` considers an edge-case that you will probably never need in *regular* code, specifically what it says about the decoder and surrogates. The point here is that some code-points are encoded as surrogate pairs, which *in unfortunate cases* can mean that it straddles two calls to `GetBytes()` / `GetChars` (on the encoder/decoder). As a consequence, the implementation may *theoretically* have a single byte/character still buffered and waiting to be processed, therefore `GetMaxByteCount` needs to warn about this.

However! All of this only makes sense if you are using the encoder/decoder directly. If you are using operations on the `Encoding`, such as `Encoding.GetBytes`, then all of this is abstracted away from you *and you will never need to know*. In which case, just use `IsSingleByte` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the example from [Encoding.Convert Method page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx#Y240)

The `Encoding.Convert` method should provide an ASCII encoded string. Hopefully single byte..

Comment: `Encoding.Convert( ... )` returns a `Byte[]` instead of a single byte, which means there's a heap allocation going on.